# Why does buildozer need to refresh sources from google repository?

Tags: android, python, kivy

Every time I run buildozer, it always refreshes sources from google repository, which takes many, many hours, and gives me an error in the end(can't install build tools). I have downloaded android sdk and ndk, and downloaded build tools, platform tools, ndk, and set it in the .spec file, could I skip this step and build my app?
Thanks!

**Edit**:I have downloaded android adk, ndk and buildtools, and configure .spec file to use them, then I waited for several hours this afternoon for buildozer to refresh sources, and finally it succeeded to package them! What I use is the kivycatalog demo in the kivy sources. But it failed in my phone. I think it's related to another problem(use of rstdocument makes it crash), (have anyone compiled the demo in kivy?) and what I want to know in this problem is how to skip the refresh sources step......

Comment: Is your buildozer up to date? Try installing from the master branch on github if not.

Comment: I install buildozer by git clone git://github.com/kivy/buildozer
cd buildozer
sudo python2.7 setup.py install. I use ubuntu 14.04 and set the output level of buildozer to 2(debug), and found it spends a lot of time on refreshing sources.

Comment: And it seems buildozer can't install something due to network problems